# AnimationDrawable OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, animationdrawable

Current Version: **Android Studio 2.2.3**

I will start by asking, how do you create an animation-list? When you click on the res/drawable folder **new -> Drawable resource file** you don't have the option to change the Root Element from selector to animation-list. So I change it manually.

Nevermind, I followed the [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) from developers.android.

Here is the code:

**res/drawable/anim.xml**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame13" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame14" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame15" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame16" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame17" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame18" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame19" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame20" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame21" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame22" android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame23" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/anim"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imageView;
AnimationDrawable a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim);
    a = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        a.start();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

You see anything wrong?

I don't at least and when I run it, this error pops up:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: animation.aggelonias.gr.animation, PID: 1146
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3077)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1624)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3059)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1017)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1076)
                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                  at animation.aggelonias.gr.animation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Somewhere in that mess says, **MainActivity.java:17**: which is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to load just 2 or 3 frames? Bitmaps eat memory, and that's the error

Comment: And how fix it?

Comment: There are a lot of topics on this. I don't know about animations though. https://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html

Comment: Basically, it just comes down to compressing your images better. JPG files, for example have a lot of wasted space, and PNG or GIF files might be better

Comment: The link is useful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your image files frame13, 14 ,...  would be very large or your image type would not be a standard image type such as png, jpg.
Check your image files.

Try adding android:largeHeap="true", in the manifest to see if this solves it.

Comment: Try adding android:largeHeap="true", in the manifest to see if this solves it.

Or Use api inSampleSize of bitmapfactory to sample the images.

Comment: final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;

Comment: Before setContentView(R.layout.activity_main),

Comment: But I tried having only 2 frames inside the animation-list, and it works. So I guess it's indeed out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimationDrawable` will load all pictures into memory,if your Animation
contains many frames, it may cause *Out Of Memory*. so you should try to compress your bitmap. Another method, you can use `SurfaceView` instead of `AnimationDrawable`.

[View here](https://github.com/yuyashuai/SurfaceViewFrameAnimation)